# Test image onload inside react component using enzyme, sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai-enzyme

I'm trying to test that a function callback is being called for an image inside my component.

This is the component:

```
const ImageById = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.url} onLoad={props.onLoad} onError={props.onError} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And my test mounts the component and then spy the callback function:

```
describe('ImageById', () => {
  it('should call load or error', () => {
    let callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    let comp = mount(ImageById, {url: 'some-url', onLoad: callbackSpy, onError: callbackSpy});
    expect(callbackSpy.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

The test fails because the inner `Img` tag is never calling its `onload` nor `onerror` methods. In production the code is working fine, it might be something related to the test environment. Its like `Img` tag doesn't react to the `url` being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that mounting the component doesn't causes `load` and `error` events to occur. I found a way of simulate them using `TestUtils` like this:

```
var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  },
  propTypes: {
    children: PropTypes.object
  }
});

describe('ImageById', () => {
  it('should call load or error', () => {
    let callbackSpy = sinon.spy();
    // need to wrap `Images` inside a class component because `renderIntoDocument`
    // wont render pure functional components.
    // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4692#issuecomment-163029873
    var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Wrapper><ImageById url={'some-url'} onLoad={callbackSpy} onError={callbackSpy} /></Wrapper>);
    var image = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'img');
    TestUtils.Simulate.load(image);
    expect(callbackSpy.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```